# Access Database VB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database built in access
I need to create a button where I click it and it will open a folder related to `Employee ID`
the problem is that the employee's folders are named as `John Mich 000321` where the `000321` is john Employee Id

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub

```
Private Sub cmdOpenEmpFolder_Click()
Dim partialName As String, partialFolder As String
Dim folderName As String
Dim folderfullPath As String

    partialName = CStr(Me.txtEmployeeID)

    partialFolder = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\"
    folderName = Dir(partialFolder & "*" & partialName, vbDirectory)
    folderfullPath = partialFolder & folderName
    Debug.Print "explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & folderfullPath & Chr(34)
    Shell "explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & folderfullPath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your response, using your first code "cmdOpenEmpFolder_Click()"  I managed to  open the main folder but, I need to find the folder of the employee and open it ( Note: that i have many folders named the sam way as: Emplyee name Stafff number)

Comment: i forget to say that in my database the staff number dosnot have the 000

Comment: no issue. Then add these zeros to codes if folder name contains these zeros. Add few screenshots for better understanding.